# Property 'slick' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, slick.js

I have an Angular 6 project that I want to use [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with. First I installed jQuery

> npm i jquery

and then slick carousel

> npm i slick-carousel

I then made the necessary edits to my angular.json file

```
"styles": [
 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
 "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
 "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"

],
 "scripts": [
 "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
 "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
]
```

Then I create a simple slider layout

```
<div class="mySlider">
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
  <div><h3>4</h3></div>
  <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

In my typescript, first I import * from jquery.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

And finally, I call the slick method in the ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.mySlider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    });
  }
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error message:

> ERROR in src/app/components/slider/slider.component.ts(20,22): error
>   TS2551: Property 'slick' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.
>   Did you mean 'click'?

So I tried to declare slick as a variable at the top of the file.

```
declare var slick: any;
```

But this didn't help. So I tried to create an import like I do with jQuery.

```
import * as slick from 'slick-carousel';
```

but that only gives me the following error message when trying to compile:

> ERROR in src/app/components/slider/slider.component.ts(3,24): error
>   TS2306: File 'D:/developement/DDI World Front
>   End/DDIWorld_frontEnd/node_modules/@types/slick-carousel/index.d.ts'
>   is not a module.

I'm not sure what else to try or what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

Here is my full slider.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
// import * as slick from 'slick-carousel';
// declare var slick: any;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.mySlider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Edit

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://angular-xyfexj.stackblitz.io/) but I'm getting a different error there.

Comment: Angular specifically states that it's not recomended to import jquery. It defeats the purpose of what angular is for. With that being said, if you still require jquery (based on your other packages, jquery is a heavy dependency so you probably will), first make sure jquery is even being loaded up. To test this, try a `console.log($)` to see if it logs undefined or a function. If it logs a function, you're good to go. The only secondary step is that you need to declare jquery in your component since jquery is exeactly up to date with es6 imports: put this at the top `declare const jQuery = $;`

Comment: If you put together a stackblitz of a simplified example, I can help troubleshoot further

Comment: Yeah, I know but it's pretty important to me to be able to use a few libraries to depend on jQuery. I was able to confirm jQuery works by using it's .text() method. I even had intellisense. I added a stack blitz.

Comment: if you are trying to use a library that depends on jQuery on an Angular project....don't use it. or check if they have a npm that doesn't need jquery

Comment: That seems to be a common theme. I'm depending on jQuery for slick slider and bootstrap. But I don't need jQuery for bootstraps grid and I could probably make my own slider without a library.

Comment: adding `declare const $: any;` to the top of my component file worked for me at least. Compiled with no issues.

Comment: There is ngx-bootstrap for an Angular implementation of Bootstrap and take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel

Answer (score 3):

Import jQuery in this way:

```
declare var $: any;
```

Change the code to this:

```
(<any>$('.mySlider')).slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @jesser is right.

Used something like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as slick from 'slick-carousel';
```

..

```
  // then in function:
  require('../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js');

  (<any>$('.slider-wrap')).slick({
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000
});
```

p.s: install slick carousel and jQuery before:

```
npm install jquery@>=1.8.0 --save-dev 
npm i slick-carousel
```