# jQuery Validate Plugin not Working with Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-validate

Can't seem to get jQuery validate pluging to work with Typescript.

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hi')
})
```

This gives a compilation error:
' Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate();
})
```

Tried installing:
npm install --save @types/jquery.validation

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section">
        <div class="wrapper"></div>
        <form class="form__box" id="form">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <input name="email" type="text">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="text">
            <button>SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="/scripts.js">   
    </script>
</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").validate();
})
```

Comment: Yes. Still not working. Forgot to remove parenthesis after trying to cast it type 'any'. Doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: Try:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423755/594235

Comment: This seem to be an issue with how you're using Typescript as opposed to anything to do with jQuery Validate.